# Validate React Native Component with Asynchronous Work

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a basic component that calls a webservice during the componentDidMount phase and overwrites the `contents` value in my state:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from "react-native";

class Widget extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            contents: 'Loading...'
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState(...this.state, {
            contents: await this.getSomeContent()
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>{this.state.contents}</Text>
        )
    }

    async getSomeContent() {
        try {
            return await (await fetch("http://someurl.com")).text()
        } catch (error) {
            return "There was an error";
        }
    }
}

export default Widget;
```

I would like to use Jest snapshots to capture the state of my component in each one of the following scenarios:

- Loading
- Success
- Error

The problem is that I have to introduce flaky pausing to validate the state of the component.

For example, to see the success state, you must place a small pause after rendering the component to give the setState method a chance to catch up:

```
test('loading state', async () => {

    fetchMock.get('*', 'Some Content');
    let widget = renderer.create(<Widget />);

    // --- Pause Here ---
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

    expect(widget.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I'm looking for the best way to overcome the asynchronicity in my test cases so that I can properly validate the snapshot of each state.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the asynchronous call out of `setState`, you can delay `setState` until the network call has resolved.  Then you can use `setState's` optional callback (which fires after the state change) to capture the state.

So, something like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
 var result = await this.getSomeContent()
 this.setState(...this.state, {
     contents: result
 },
 // setState callback- fires when state changes are complete.
 ()=>expect(this.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
 );
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to specify the validation outside of the component, you could create a prop, say, `stateValidation` to pass in a the validation function:

```
jest('loading state', async () => {

    fetchMock.get('*', 'Some Content');

    jestValidation = () => expect(widget.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();

    let widget = renderer.create(<Widget stateValidaton={jestValidation}/>); 

});
```

then use the prop in the component:

```
async componentDidMount() {
 var result = await this.getSomeContent()
 this.setState(...this.state, {
     contents: result
 },
 // setState callback- fires when state changes are complete.
 this.props.stateValidaton
 );
}
```

Comment: This solution would put the Jest validation inside of the implementation, which is not desired inside the application.

Comment: How about passing it in to the component as a prop?  See the "UPDATE" section above.

Comment: I still believe this will make the test and the component too tightly coupled. I actually ended up solving this by using Redux to separate the concerns and let the component simply use a given state. I think that ends up being cleaner.